# Webpack authored library ReferenceError: react is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I've searched and searched, but can't find an answer. Losing hope.

Here's the issue:

I have a component library that's built on React 17. I've bundled it using webpack 4.
The bundle gets generated and there don't seem to be any issues with it, until I tag it and attempt to use it in my work app.

Then I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: react is not defined`

[image: Lib bug]

The app compiles just fine, no errors. It only crashes when trying to use it.

Here's my webpack config for the library:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const flexBugFixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes');
const presetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const normalize = require('postcss-normalize');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
// const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'RenezaComponents',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                [
                  '@babel/preset-react',
                  {
                    runtime: 'automatic'
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          },
          'ts-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  flexBugFixes,
                  presetEnv({
                    autoprefixer: {
                      flexbox: 'no-2009'
                    },
                    stage: 3
                  }),
                  autoprefixer,
                  normalize()
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        sideEffects: true
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  flexBugFixes,
                  presetEnv({
                    autoprefixer: {
                      flexbox: 'no-2009'
                    },
                    stage: 3
                  }),
                  autoprefixer,
                  normalize()
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.(woff(2)?|ttf)/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  externals: nodeExternals()
};
```

The library gets installed using `npm` from our work private repository.

Example:

```js
import { Button } from 'reneza-components'; // package.json has this as the library name
```

I've tried mucking about with externals, but none of them work. It always complains about the same thing.

The only other solution right now that I can come up with is just bundling react with it so it'd shut up. But that's not optimal.

I'm out of ideas. Perhaps anyone here would be a bit more clever than me?

Edit: Even bundling it together makes it throw the same error. So I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Do you have it listed as peer dependency in the lib package json. You could also try to export to cjs and see if that works. Personally I have found rollup much easier for component libraries

Comment: We used to use rollup. But the typescript plugin doesn't support React 17 new JSX factory. So we had to ditch it. I'll try listing, the deps under peerDependencies.

Comment: Sadly, peerDependencies didn't help. Time to revert back to React 16.8. A day wasted. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Ah :( Did you try the other formats, esm, cjs? I am bundling a react 17 lib using rollup without problems, but maybe its just because I am not using a features you are https://github.com/JazzBrown1/react-unicode-editor/

Comment: Yup, tried both. Normally we out put to both, esm and cjs. The issue with rollup is that the new jsx-runtime has a type conflict, and the rollup-plugin-typescript2 just falis. The transpiled version thinks that `jsx` is not exported from the package.